# Charts on Phonegap Application

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

i've been trying with several Chart plugins for jquery, and whenever y try to diplay a chart i get an error like this:

06-22 18:53:46.800: E/Web Console(5446): Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new v.fn.init(e,t,n)} has no method 'plot' at file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js:42

I tried with jqplot, flot, and highcharts. My app is working on an android device, and also uses Handlebars.

If someone could help me figure out why i'm getting the error (or has been in the same situation) and get the plugin working. I don't know if it's something wrong with the plugin or with my implementation. I've imported all the corresponding JS, and CSS files for the plugin.

Thx.